# Silverstripe URL Mapping to Action

Tags: url, routes, silverstripe

I am trying to map a certain URL to a certain Controller action.  Currently I have an MVC setup in the project where site.com/members/view/1 will show me first member and site.com/members/edit/1 will edit the first member.  Then if I go to site.com/members/add will give me the registration form.  I want to go to site.come/register and get the form that site.com/members/add hands out.

So far I have tried with routing in routes.yml file, here is what I did:

```
Name: mysiteroutes
Before: '*'
After:
  - '#rootroutes'
  - '#coreroutes'
  - '#modelascontrollerroutes'
  - '#adminroutes'
---
Director:
  rules:
    'register': 'MembersPage_Controller'
```

This has worked to an extent.  If I go to site.com/register/add it will give me the form.  I am trying to figure out how to remove the add part.  How do I tell it so that when you go to site.com/register load MembersPage_Controller/add action?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i don't know if it's possible to route to one action directly using Director's rules.

But you could subclass the existing controller, and make "add" action the default action for this one, e.g.

```
Class MemberAddController extends MemberPage_Controller {
    private static $url_handlers = array(
        '' => 'add'
    );
}
```

and in your config.yml:

```
Director:
  rules:
    'register': 'MemberAddController'
```

Of course you can add this `$url_handlers` value to your existing controller, if the index method is unused.

Comment: That is a clever workaround, except that I do make use of the index.  Index will be a page that lists me members.

Comment: Index of MemberPage_Controller lists members... 
Index of MemberAddController (subclass) could show the form...?

Comment: I see what you mean now.  Still to me its a workaround, which I could also just make a Register page and move all the logic there.  Its really hard to believe that you can't specify action on the re-route, seems like a huge flaw.